# Sybase to equivalent Oracle convert function

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

I have a working SQL query with a `WHERE` clause that is Sybase specific, and would like to find the equivalent in Oracle (I tried a couple of things with `CAST`, `BINARY`... nothing conclusive so far).

Basically, I'm trying to check if a specific binary flag (`value = 2`) is raised or not. Here is the where clause:

```
WHERE (convert(binary,convert(int,MY_FIELD)) & 2)=0
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the original type of the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
where bitand(cast(MY_FIELD as number), 2) = 0
```

`bitand()` (documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm)) is the equivalent of `&`.

Comment: Indeed... this is the solution. 
And when you gave me the solution, I realized I already found it a couple of months ago (it was in an old email I wrote... ).

Thanks a lot !